Proof of Real Nullstellensatz Question
I don't understand a step in the proof of the Real Nullstellensatz from Bochnak, Coste, Roy's text. When they come to prove the real Nullstellensatz, they say that by this Lemma 4.1.5. they can assume I is a real prime ideal (see underlined sentence). I don't understand why: It seems what they end up proving is that there exists a real prime ideal J containing I for which J = I(Z(J)), how does that tell me anything about the original ideal I? Thank you,


Suppose $I\subseteq R[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ is a real ideal. Since $R[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ is Noetherian, there are finitely many minimal prime ideals containing $I$, call them $P_1,\dots,P_n$. By Lemma 4.1.5, $I$ is radical, so $I = \bigcap_{i=1}^n P_i \newcommand{\I}{\mathcal{I}}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathcal{Z}}$. Thus:
\begin{align*}
\I(\Z(I)) &= \I\left(\Z\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n P_i\right)\right)\\
&= \I\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n\Z\left( P_i\right)\right)\\
&= \bigcap_{i=1}^n\I\left(\Z\left( P_i\right)\right).\\
\end{align*}
By Lemma 4.1.5 again, each $P_i$ is real, so if we show that $\I(\Z(P)) = P$ when $P$ is a real prime ideal, we will have $$\I(\Z(I)) = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \I(\Z(P_i)) = \bigcap_{i=1}^n P_i = I.$$
Here we used the fact that $\I$ and $\Z$ swap finite intersections and unions, which are elementary properties of these operators.
